# Updating minSdkVersion from 3 to 4 - will it affect existing api 3 users?

Tags: android

I have an app on the marketplace, minSdkVersion is set to "3". I want to change it to "4" in my next release. Will existing android 1.5 users be affected by this, if they already have my app installed? I'm hoping they can continue using the app as is, they just wouldn't see it appear in the marketplace anymore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android 1.5 users who have already installed the app won't be affected, but they won't be able to update the app and use newer versions. That's because the minSdkVersion is now 4, and they use Android 1.5. They will neither see any updates nor be able to install it (if they uninstall the current version).

Answer (score 1):

They will continue to be able to use the application that is installed on their phone. However, if they remove it, they won't be able to download it again. It shouldn't remove it from their phone if they do an update, if that is what you are worried about. It just won't see the update.